# Passing anonymous JS function as a callback

Tags: javascript, callback, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to understand callbacks in JS. Here is the example I am working with at the moment:

```
getData('http://fakedomain1234.com/userlist', writeData);

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += "show this before data ...";

function getData(dataURI, callback) {
    // Normally you would actually connect to a server here.
    // We're just going to simulate a 3-second delay.
    var timer = setTimeout(function () {
        var dataArray = [123, 456, 789, 012, 345, 678];
        callback(dataArray);
    }, 3000);
}

function writeData(myData) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += myData;
}
```

My question is: is it possible to pass an anonymous function to `getData()` instead of a function that is already defined? If so, how would you got about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like the function you passed to `setTimeout`

```
getData('http://fakedomain1234.com/userlist', function(myData) {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += myData;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like you said:

```
getData('http://fakedomain1234.com/userlist', function(data) {
    // contents of anonymous function
});
```

Comment: Oh... If that's the way I pass the function, can it still be invoked in getData the same way?

Comment: I had trouble picturing that when you pass an anonymous function as a variable then it's exactly like passing a defined function. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: The trick here is that you can write the anonymous function in place of the callback argument. The language allows that, defining and passing the lambda function in the same place